# how to control camera retake in ziggeo for Ionic 3 framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-camera, ziggeo-api, ziggeo-sdk

How to control the camera retake in Ziggeo for Ionic3. Ziggeo is taking the user to the camera and according to the device option, their user can take a lot of retakes. is it possible to stop the camera retakes or user may reflect back to ionic app as soon as user take video (Stop recording button).

I tried to found this on Ziggeo documentation but didn't got succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first mention that I work at Ziggeo. Now with that being said, lets get cracking :)

When camera is requested on the desktop systems the browsers talk to OS and OS talks to the drivers. The drivers talk with the camera and provide the video data. On the mobile devices this is slightly different.

The mobile browser will ask the system, which will reply by activating the camera app. The camera app is different for different versions of system and system itself, however in general they refuse to listen for any parameters that are sent to them from browser.

This is why you might see the option to retake the recording on the mobile devices.

The purpose of Ziggeo is to however provide a way to use camera and mic in many ways.  As such there is a way to actually skip the native app and go to a new way of recording videos.

This is accomplished by adding the `webrtc_on_mobile` parameter when you are creating your app.

```
var ziggeoApp = new ZiggeoApi.V2.Application({
    token:"APPLICATION_TOKEN",
    webrtc_streaming_if_necessary: true,
    webrtc_on_mobile: true
});
```

Now the above is just the HTML version of it. The Ionic is a bit different. Currently it is not possible, however it will be possible in the next update.

Edit 2020:
To support iOS `webrtc_streaming_if_necessary: true` was created. This is because the WebRTC implementation of WebRTC on those systems is for streaming, not the standard WebRTC. By using it, you make sure that you are not using the WebRTC Streaming unless it is actually necessary to do so.

Added the way you would use it in the above code.

You can always check and find the latest on the header building page on Ziggeo here: https://ziggeo.com/docs/sdks/javascript/browser-integration/header

Comment: Bane, I think `webrtc_streaming_if_necessary` should also be added, right?

Comment: Yes, `webrtc_streaming_if_necessary` as well you are right Shashank :) Updated the comment.